# Is there macOS git GUI that supports git --word-diff?

Tags: git, macos

About half of my use of Git involves writing documents (mostly LaTeX). I use a GUI Git client to manage my document history. I've been frustrated by most clients because they don't support --word-diff, so every time I change a few words in a long paragraph the entire paragraph is marked as changed in the history view.

Is there a GUI Git client for macOS out there that supports --word-diff instead of the default 'line' diff?

Comment: You may consider turning off line wrapping and writing a single line per sentence.  That's the approach I typically use for text.

Answer (score 1):

An editor like [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac) would show you word diff, similar to what [diff-highlight does in command line](https://coderwall.com/p/nl-bdg/more-readable-git-word-diff-on-osx)

You can find an illustration of that idea in "[One-keystroke git commits with Visual Studio Code](https://bytearcher.com/articles/one-keystroke-git-commits-with-visual-studio-code/#viewing-changes)" from **[Panu Pitkamaki](https://bytearcher.com/contact/)**.

[image: https://bytearcher.com/articles/one-keystroke-git-commits-with-visual-studio-code/diff.jpg]